# How to set two different onClick listeners for two different recyclerviews in same activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I have an Activity with two different recycler views.and for them two Adapters.

1. DrawerAdapter.
   I have set an onClickListner Interface and implimented in Activity class.

> DrawerAdapter

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.DrawerItemViewHolder>{

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResID;
    ArrayList<DrawerItem> menuList;
    onItemClickListner mListner;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    WebView webViewLayout;
    LinearLayout mDrawerListParent;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    int[] drawer_icons=new int[]{R.drawable.dr_plus,R.drawable.dr_plus_square,R.drawable.dr_search,R.drawable.dr_tasks,R.drawable.dr_dashboard
            ,R.drawable.dr_buy_dashboard,R.drawable.dr_add_user2,R.drawable.dr_table,R.drawable.dr_status_map,R.drawable.dr_trackchanges
            ,R.drawable.dr_templates};



    public interface onItemClickListner{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }



    public class DrawerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       TextView itemTitle;
       ImageView itemIcon;
       onItemClickListner listner;
       RelativeLayout dItemParentLayout;

        public DrawerItemViewHolder(View itemView, final onItemClickListner listner) {
            super(itemView);
            itemTitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_title);
            itemIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_icon);

            this.listner=listner;
            dItemParentLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.d_item);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (listner!=null){
                       int position=DrawerItemViewHolder.this.getAdapterPosition();
                       if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                           listner.onItemClick(position);
                                                  }
                   }
                }
            });
        }
    }//ViewHolder

    public DrawerAdapter(int resource, ArrayList<DrawerItem> itemList, WebView webViewLayout,
                         DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout, RecyclerView mDrawerList, LinearLayout drawerListParent,
                         Toolbar pToolbar,onItemClickListner listner){

        layoutResID=resource;
        menuList=itemList;
        mListner=listner;
        this.mDrawerLayout=mDrawerLayout;
        this.mDrawerList=mDrawerList;
        this.webViewLayout=webViewLayout;
        this.mDrawerListParent=drawerListParent;
        toolbar=pToolbar;
    }



    //======================================================================================
    @Override
    public DrawerItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item,parent,false);
        DrawerItemViewHolder dvh=new DrawerItemViewHolder(v,mListner);
     return dvh;
    }
    //======================================================================================

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DrawerItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final DrawerItem currentItem=menuList.get(position);

       // holder.itemIcon.setImageResource(drawer_icons[position]);
        holder.itemTitle.setText(currentItem.getTitle());

        holder.dItemParentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ONCLICK EVENTS
                System.out.print("CLICKED AT:"+position +"\n");

                webViewLayout.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                toolbar.setSubtitle(currentItem.title);

//                toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.car3);
                String xurl="someURL/"+currentItem.getLinkURL();
                webViewLayout.loadUrl(xurl);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListParent);
            }
        });
    }
    //======================================================================================

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menuList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }


}
```

2. NotificationAdapter.
   i have set an onclick listner in the onBindViewHolder of notificationAdapter.

> NotificationAdapter

```
    public class NoificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoificationAdapter.NotificationHolder> {
    private ArrayList<NotificationItem> notificationItems;
    private onItemClickListner mListner;
    private int layoutResID,notificationposition;
    Context myContext;

    String notificationDate,notificationRecType;



    String []myc={"#43A047","#C62828","#039BE5","#F57C00","#4A148C","#43A047",
            "#039BE5","#C62828","#43A047","#C62828","#039BE5","#F57C00","#4A148C",
            "#43A047","#039BE5","#C62828"};


    public interface onItemClickListner{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public static class NotificationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView mNotificationTextView;
        RelativeLayout mNotificaionHolderLayout;
        ImageView imageDelete;
        String mNotificationURL;
        String mNotificationDate;
        String mNotificationRT;
        onItemClickListner listner;

        public NotificationHolder(View itemView,final onItemClickListner listner) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listner=listner;
            mNotificationTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.NotificationTextView);
            mNotificaionHolderLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification__item_container);
            imageDelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_delete_image);
            mNotificationRT=null;
            mNotificationURL=null;
            mNotificationDate=null;

//            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    if (listner != null) {
//                        int position = NotificationHolder.this.getAdapterPosition();
//                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
//                            listner.onItemClick(position);
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//            });
        }
    }//END OF NOTIFICATION_VH

    public NoificationAdapter(Context context,int resource,ArrayList<NotificationItem> notificationList,onItemClickListner listner){
        myContext=context;
        layoutResID=resource;
        notificationItems=notificationList;
        mListner=listner;
        notificationposition=0;
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_notificationitem,parent,false);
        NotificationHolder evh=new NotificationHolder(v,mListner);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotificationHolder holder, int position) {

        final NotificationItem currentItem=notificationItems.get(position);

        notificationposition=currentItem.getPositionNumber();
        if (notificationposition>=myc.length){
            if (notificationposition%2==0){
                holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myc[0]));
                holder.imageDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myc[0]));
            }else {
                holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myc[2]));
                holder.imageDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myc[2]));
            }
        }

        holder.mNotificaionHolderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myc[notificationposition]));
        holder.imageDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myc[notificationposition]));

        holder.mNotificationTextView.setText(currentItem.getNotification_name());
        holder.mNotificationURL=currentItem.getNotification_link();
        holder.mNotificationDate=currentItem.getNotification_date();
        holder.mNotificationRT=currentItem.getNotification_rT();

        if (!holder.mNotificationURL.isEmpty()){
            holder.imageDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        holder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                deleteNotification(currentItem);


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationItems.size();
    }



//Delete from View
    public void deleteNotification(NotificationItem todelete){
        int notificationPosition=notificationItems.indexOf(todelete);
        notificationItems.remove(notificationPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(notificationPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(notificationPosition);
    }

}
```

when I added this two adapters in my activity ,if I scroll through notification first,then drawer want scroll.vice versa,only one listner is working, the one which used first .

> Activity.java

```
       public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DrawerAdapter.onItemClickListner,NoificationAdapter.onItemClickListner{

 //in fill drawer function   
         drawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItemList,
                                webViewLayout, mDrawerLayout, mDrawerList,
                                mDrawerParent,mToolbar,
                                NavigationDrawerActivity.this);
                        drawerAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                        mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
     //in fill notification function   
                           nfAdapter=new NoificationAdapter(NavigationDrawerActivity.this,
                        R.id.listView_Notific_Link, notificationList,nListner);
                lvNotification.setAdapter(nfAdapter);
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If both listener has different functionality then create two Different Listeners

Comment: I did. implemented one in onBIndview in NotificationAdapter.and the other one in activity class overriding the onitemclick function set in the interface in DrawerAdapter.Still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This involves little code change.

**Listener1**

```
interface Listener1 {
 
    function1();

}
```

**Listener2**

```
interface Listener2 {
 
    function1(){}
   
}
```

**Activity code**

```
YourActivity implements Listener1, Listener2 {
    
     // Override functionality 
     function1(){}
 
     function2(){}

    // Pass reference to Adapters like this 

    drawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerItemList,
                            webViewLayout, mDrawerLayout, mDrawerList,
                            mDrawerParent,mToolbar,
                            YourActivity.this);
                    

}
```

**Most Important thing Typecast your listener in your Adapters**

```
NotificationAdapter {
   
     Listener1 listener1; 
      
     NotificationAdapter(whatever, .... , listener1){
       
       listener1 = (Listener1)listener1     // Because by default it will be YourActivity. This is how inheritance works. 
      
     }
}
```

**Do the same thing for Another adapter taking Listener2 as an instance variable.**

Comment: thanks, Rohit, i have done this and no matter what, only one of two is working, if I choose drawer first and scroll then I can't open notification. if I open notification first I can't scroll or select drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Change DrawerAdapter.DrawerAdapter to this:

```
public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onDrawerItemClick(int position);
}
```

What's happening is that in your Activity you have one method called onItemClick. You set a clicklistener in both adapters which call that method. So both adapters end up calling the exact same onItemClick when they are clicked. All you need to do is figure out a way to tell which adapter was clicked. There are a lot of ways to do that, I think the one above is the simplest.

Comment: I have changed the name to onDrawerItemClick and for the notification drawer, I have a listener set in onBindView.which calls a function in the adapter to delete the item from the list. When I tested, first drawer worked fine then I deleted the notification, then again when I opened the drawer, nothing. not even scrolling is working...any thoughts?